# Debug feature files in visual studio code

Tags: cucumberjs

I am trying to debug my scripts in visual studio code. I am using protractor and cucumberjs in my automation framework.
I have mentioned cucumber.js filepath and my feature filepath in my launch.json.

It is able to find my feature file but it is not able to find the step definition file for the feature file.So I am getting the following error:

> Undefined. Implement with the following snippet:

Comment: Hello and welcome.  Can you add the "following snippet" into your question so that people can help you better?

Comment: sorry..here is the error vs code is throwing when I try to debug                                                    Scenario: User rewards - Eligible user sees all the components within survey module - site_tests\features\sprint\my.feature:59
 Step: When I dismiss a question then I dont get any points - site_tests\features\sprint\my.feature:56
 Message:
 Undefined. Implement with the following snippet:
 this.When(/^I dismiss a question then I dont get any points$/, function (callback) {
 // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
 callback(null, 'pending');
});

Comment: Please include the relevant section from your launch.json in the question. Preferably also show your relative file structure